# Why is my Linkbuttons command function not getting trigged?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code in my codebehind:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < linkList.Count; i++)
            {
                var link = UppercaseFirst(linkList[i]);
                var linkButton = new LinkButton
                    {
                        Text = link + " > ",
                        ID = Convert.ToString(i),
                        CommandArgument = urlList[i]
                    };
                linkButton.Command += new CommandEventHandler(lnkWeb_Click);
                bcHolder.Controls.Add(linkButton);

            }
```

and here is the lnkWeb_Click method:

```
protected void lnkWeb_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
        {
          var url = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
          //code...
        }
```

This method is not getting triggered when I click on one of those generated linkbuttons.

Anyone have any idea what the problem is?

Tried `OnCommand="lnkWeb_Click"` in the aspx file and the method got trigged, but not those that I generate by code. They dont even have `OnCommand="lnkWeb_Click"` attribute.

Comment: When and how are you calling the code that adds link buttons to the page?

Comment: It occures everytime lnkWeb_Click is trigged by other linkbuttons

Comment: So user clicks button (1), they add more buttons (2) to the page, user clicks one of (2) buttons, and its handler is not called. Right?

Comment: Yes they click on the other linkbuttons that have OnCommand="lnkWeb_Click" and then it runs and generates the 5 linkbuttons. But those generated linkbuttons handler is not called exacly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is with the control life cycle. If you want to handle events of some control properly - you have to add this control to the page on every page loading process, that is on every postback.

Look what happens in your case:

1. Initial button is clicked
2. During the post back your dynamic link buttons are added to the page, event handlers are assigned to them
3. User clicks on the newly generated link button
4. During post back these dynamic link buttons are not added to the page again, ASP.NET does not know the origin of a event so it does not call the handler.

To fix this you might need to store in the View State information about link buttons that have to be added (please do not store the controls themselves, that would be a huge overhead). Also pay attention to their IDs - they have to be the same for the same controls.

**Update.** Some more hints on the View State solution.

Basically you need some indicator that during the page loading you need to create some dynamic link buttons. The very basic way to do it is to store the list of the link button identifiers (or texts, or both) and then during `Page_Load` check if there is anything stored in View State. For example:

```
// Property to access the view state data
protected List<string> Links
{
    get { return ViewState['links']; }
    set { ViewState['links'] = value; }
}

...

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    if (this.Links != null && this.Links.Count > 0)
    {
        // inside this method you create your link buttons and add them to the page
        // you actually have this code already
        RenderLinkButtons();
    }
}

...

// Not sure about what name you have here
protected void InitialButtonHandlerName(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> linkList = ...; //your variable, guessing a type

    // this is exactly the method you use already to add links to the page
    // just one more action added to it - store info about these links into View State to use it on later post backs
    this.Links = linkList;
    RenderLinkButtons();    
}
```

Please use it just a point in right direction - you might have different implementation depending on your requirements and preferences. But I hope concept is clear now.

Comment: is storing in view state the only option, is there no simple fix?

Comment: @Obsivus, unfortunately this is the only one I can think of (there might be other still, I just do not know them). Dynamic controls are tricky creatures. However View State way is not that bad. At very least it can be just `ViewState['links'] = new List<string>()`, and then on page load check: if there is something in `ViewState['links']` - render links, otherwise do nothing. You have already done most of the work

Comment: on exacly what things should i use viewstate on?

Comment: @Obsivus, all right, updated the answer with some code samples to clarify the general idea.

Comment: I tried this there is a problem the lnkWeb_Click() method where i store the info about the links with ViewState seems to fire after page load beacuse when I click on a linkbutton nothing happens but when the page loads it works!

Comment: @Obsivus, sorry, I might not understood your problem correctly, but this is by design. I mean `lnkWeb_Click()` as well as any other control handler is always handled *after* the `Page_Load`. So what you should do is: when `lnkWeb` is clicked at first render the links right away, and on the consequent postbacks check ViewState in `Page_Load` and render links there.