# Can't seem to make OnClick event fire

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, onclick, click

Trying to figure out why this code seems to be ignoring the `Click` event on my delete button. I have tried `OnClientClick`, `Click` and both at the same time just to see if one would take. Since this is apparently coming off as confusing, to make it clear what I mean when I say "delete button", my issue comes in on this line: `btn.Click += btn_Click;`

The `btn_Click` is never firing, tried to step through it with the debugger and it never even made it to this point. Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong and possibly offer up some suggestions of how to fix it?

Below I have included literally ALL of my code for this application.

### HTML

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="searchPool" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>

<asp:Label ID="lblSearchItem" runat="server">Item</asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox id="txtSearchItem" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Label ID="lblDescription" runat="server">Description</asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox id="txtDescription" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Label ID="lblPath" runat="server">Path</asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox id="txtPath" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnNewSearchItem" runat="server" OnClick="btnNewSearchItem_Click"/>
```

### C

```
        public class SearchObject
        {
            private string _item;
            private string _description;
            private string _path;

            public SearchObject(string item, string description, string path)
            {
                Item = item;
                Description = description;
                Path = path;
            }

            public string Item {get; set;}
            public string Description {get; set;}
            public string Path {get; set;}
        }
        public static List<SearchObject> searchObjects = new List<SearchObject>();

        private void DisplayItems()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < searchObjects.Count(); i++)
            {
                Panel pnl = new Panel();
                pnl.ID = string.Format("panel{0}", i);
                TextBox txtItem = new TextBox();
                txtItem.ID = string.Format("panel{0}", i);
                txtItem.Text = searchObjects[i].Item;
                TextBox txtDescription = new TextBox();
                txtDescription.ID = string.Format("txtItem{0}", i);
                txtDescription.Text = searchObjects[i].Description;
                TextBox txtPath = new TextBox();
                txtPath.ID = string.Format("txtPath{0}", i);
                txtPath.Text = searchObjects[i].Path;
                Button btn = new Button();
                btn.ID = string.Format("button{0}", i);
                btn.Click += btn_Click;
                btn.Attributes["RemoveIndex"] = i.ToString();

                pnl.Controls.Add(txtItem);
                pnl.Controls.Add(txtDescription);
                pnl.Controls.Add(txtPath);
                pnl.Controls.Add(btn);

                searchPool.Controls.Add(pnl);
            }
        }

        void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn = (Button)sender;
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(btn.Attributes["RemoveIndex"]);
            searchObjects.RemoveAt(index);
        }

        protected void btnNewSearchItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SearchObject oSearch = new SearchObject(txtSearchItem.Text, txtDescription.Text, txtPath.Text);
            searchObjects.Add(oSearch);
            DisplayItems();
        }
```

Comment: Where is the definition for `btnNewSearchItem_Click` in your C# code???

Comment: As always with dynamic controls - you need to add them to the page on every postback if you want their events to work correctly. For example see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22633876/why-is-my-linkbuttons-command-function-not-getting-trigged/22634239#22634239) for some details on what is going on

Comment: also where is the code for Delete Button in aspx page?

Comment: why are the answers being down voted.Your question is not at all clear and thats why such an answer from all of them.Still down vote for all of us???

Answer (score -1):

In your .aspx page, look at the OnClick. Whatever is in between the quotes needs to be the name of your method in the associated aspx.cs page. So for this:

Your method should be:

protected void btnNewSearchItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
...insert code here...
}

Comment: No, I would like the `btn_Click` to execute, not the `btnNewSearchItem_Click` method.

Comment: Share more about what causes DisplayItems() to run. It needs to be linked somehow to that or to page load, if you intend for new controls to show up then.

Answer (score -2):

Your button method must be protected void btnNewSearchItem_Click(object obj, EventArg e)